# Finding Integral Bounds to Maximize Area

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am new to StackOverflow and Calculus and have a very basic working understanding of the subject.

I have a distribution, f(x), and I need to use calculus to find the upper and lower bounds for an integral that maximizes the area underneath it, given the constraint that the upper bound must be 8 units greater than the lower bound. In pictorial terms,

$$\int_a^b f(x) \,dx= maximum$$

I need to solve for a, where b is 8 + a. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This could be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1):

pretend that $0$ is approximately in the middle of your region of interest. From the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

What are
$$  \frac{d}{dt} \; \int_0^{t+8} \; f(x) \;dx \; \; ?  $$
$$  \frac{d}{dt} \; \int_t^{0} \; f(x) \;dx \; \; ?  $$
$$  \frac{d}{dt} \; \int_t^{t+8} \; f(x) \;dx \; \; ?  $$

If you are unsure, I recommend picking a well known $f,$ for example $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+ x^2},$ with known antiderivative $\arctan x$